# pd.read_csv with keep_default_na throws TypeError for |: 'list' and 'set'

Tags: python, pandas

The following line throws a TypeError for a valid CSV input file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=index_col, sep=',|;|\\|', 
                 engine='python', keep_default_na=False)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=index_col, sep=',|;|\\|', engine='python', keep_default_na=False)
  File "B:\RCS\Production\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "B:\RCS\Production\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()
  File "B:\RCS\Production\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "B:\RCS\Production\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2007, in read
    index, columns = self._make_index(data, alldata, columns, indexnamerow)
  File "B:\RCS\Production\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1196, in _make_index
    index = self._agg_index(index)
  File "B:\RCS\Production\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1288, in _agg_index
    arr, _ = self._convert_types(arr, col_na_values | col_na_fvalues)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'set'
```

(Win)Python version 3.6.1, pandas version 0.19.2

File loads fine in 1.1.3, but upgrading is not an option. Is there any way around this error in 0.19.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replicate the behavior of `keep_default_na=False` using

```
pd.read_csv(..., na_values=set())
```

I'm using the option because `''` (the empty string) is normally parsed as nan value which in my use case was not appropriate. `na_values` specifies which strings will be parsed as nan.